Where do we get the path to newrelic.jar from?
When you add your Spring Boot web API app to New Relic for monitoring, the “guided install” instructions for Spring Boot on Windows give three steps:

add lines to pom
download newrelic.yml file
add java -javaagent:/full/path/to/newrelic.jar -jar app.jar

It's the last step we are stuck with. We assume that the POM will cause the New Relic code/JAR to be included in the app.jar, and be on the class path. This then begs the question:

Why do we have to add newrelic.jar and its path to the command line, if we already added it to the pom?
Where do we get the path to the newrelic.jar from? This was presumably downloaded and installed by the new relic POM changes. How do we know where New Relic will put it?

If we have to manually put the New Relic jar somewhere in our project, why do we need to add lines to the POM?
If we have to manually download the JAR file:

Where do we get it from (it's not mentioned in guided install)
Where should we put it in our project? We have src/main/java and src/main/resources in our project, with nothing else other than pom files etc. Where are we supposed to put New Relic JARs?

========== update 1 ============
Andre below kindly shared that the POM code is only there to download the jar. However, it doesnt seem to work, in that after building the app with maven, it does create a directory ourmodule/target/classes/newrelic but the only thing in this dir is newrelic.yml. Where does it put the jar?
I cant believe how hard the "guided install" is, its missing so much critical information.
This the code the guided install instructions tell you to add to the POM:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack-newrelic</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includeGroupIds>com.newrelic.agent.java</includeGroupIds>
                <includeArtifactIds>newrelic-java</includeArtifactIds>
                <!-- you can optionally exclude files -->
                <!-- <excludes>**/newrelic.yml</excludes> -->
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.newrelic.agent.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>newrelic-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.12.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>


The newrelic.jar is not supposed to be inside the application jar. It must be someplace else and added to the command line as described, because its processing starts before the application jar is loaded.
These additions to the pom will download the newrelic.zip from Maven Central and unzip it to your target directory. Thus the newrelic.jar file will be in target/newrelic/newrelic.jar. This location is set on the line:
<outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>

Instead of using your pom file, you could download the agent manually and save someplace in your filesystem. It should not be inside your project, as it is not supposed to be added to your application jar. Then you just reference it with -javaagent:/full/path/to/newrelic.jar as you have in step 3.

So all the pom lines are just to download it.  The question still remains, what path to I put in the java command line?  I have no idea what /full/path/to/ is or will be.  The application is deployed to a fargate service, and I have no idea what directory structure the app will end up in, or even what OS.  If we have to provide an absolute file system path, we cant.

The full path will be target/newrelic/newrelic.jar. The target directory is in the same directory as your pom file. These are instructions for a local installation of the agent. Unfortunately, it will not work for Fargate.

For Fargate, I think the easiest would be to copy both the application jar and newrelic.jar in the Docker image and use the -javaagent... in the entrypoint.

OK, so the answer was not very elegant.
Having the newrelic code in the POM serves no purpose.  Instead we manually downloaded the jar, and put it in a dir with a newrelic.yml in a random directory, then use -javaagent.
I don't see any purpose in using POM to download the jar because it cant be used as is, and also it downloads another copy of the newrelic.yml which gets used instead of ours.
